# Linux sort doesn't work with negative float numbers

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sorting, ubuntu

How to sort this kind of input?

```
0.00159265291648695254
-0.00318530179313823899
0
0.00999983333416666468
0.00362937767285478371
0.00477794259012844049
-0.00637057126765263261
0.00681464007477014026
-0.00840724736714870645
-0.00522201549675090458
```

Either `sort -n data` and `sort -g data` procudes this:

```
0
0.00159265291648695254
-0.00318530179313823899
0.00362937767285478371
0.00477794259012844049
-0.00522201549675090458
-0.00637057126765263261
0.00681464007477014026
-0.00840724736714870645
0.00999983333416666468
```

On the other hand `-1.whatever` would be in front of the zero. I need the sort to notice the minus signs. Thank you.

Comment: What flavor of UNIX are you on? My Ubuntu sorts just fine using both `-g` and `-n`.

Comment: well that's bizarre, i'm using as well ubuntu (Ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: I'm running 11.10 too. My sort gives your exact output *without any parameters* using `/usr/bin/sort` but both `-g` and `-n` work.

Comment: i tried that.. `sort is /usr/bin/sort` how to obtain the sort version?

Comment: I just don't get it, my friend's kubuntu says the same.. http://pastebin.com/zpYkrznv

Comment: Try it like this: `printf '0.03\n0.4\n-0.3\n0\n' | sort -n`  Your pastebin looks like the greater-than signs actually got into the `sort` input somehow.

Comment: sort (GNU coreutils) 8.5, looks like this could be something with local settings, i have to check it out

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All those troubles did my local settings. My ubuntu is in Czech:

```
$ echo $LANG
cs_CZ.UTF-8
```

In this local setting it's not a decimal point, rather a decimal comma that seperates integer from the rest (as we were thought in math classes, in our language we really do write comma instead of a point).

Therefore:

```
echo '0,03 >> 0,4 >
> -0,3 >
> 0' | sort -n
> 0
> -0,3 >
> 0,4 >
0,03 >
```

If you are writing a bash script, set the sorting routine to use the "normal" settings.

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be in your sort command. If I run the same my result is as expected:

```
$ echo '0.00159265291648695254
> -0.00318530179313823899
> 0
> 0.00999983333416666468
> 0.00362937767285478371
> 0.00477794259012844049
> -0.00637057126765263261
> 0.00681464007477014026
> -0.00840724736714870645
> -0.00522201549675090458' | sort -n
-0.00840724736714870645
-0.00637057126765263261
-0.00522201549675090458
-0.00318530179313823899
0
0.00159265291648695254
0.00362937767285478371
0.00477794259012844049
0.00681464007477014026
0.00999983333416666468
```

You shoud use GNU sort if not using it

```
sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

Comment: my version is even newer, so wierd

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues. For numbers between 1.0 and -1.0. sort -n (or -g) does not solve it. I finally multiplied everything with a large number, sorted it, and divided it again. Nevertheless, I cannot understand why there would be such an error in linux